# What is NHibernate session exactly?

Tags: nhibernate, session, activerecord, castle-activerecord, castle

It's a long time I'm working with NHibernate session through frameworks like Castle ActiveRecord but never understood what is a session exactly and how should manipulate. Can anybody help? Is there any concise resource?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Exactly? http://bit.ly/deqOr7

Comment: @Arnis L., would you please comment long url please? Our ISP has problems with sites like bit.ly

Comment: just pointing to source code of nhibernate. Actually - it has pretty decent Session description. Here's full URL: http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs?revision=5228&content-type=text/plain

Comment: @Arnis L., this link leaned good point about `ISession`. Why you don't provide it as a answer not a comment?

Comment: because it was supposed to be a joke until I realized that it actually provides quite a lot of information. :)

Answer (score 9):

The NHibernate session encapsulates a unit of work as specified by the [unit of work pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx).